# php script to change slug in post automatically

Tags: php, permalinks, slug

I would like a script that changes the final number I have in my slug by +1, for example if my link is https://site. com/permalink-1 number 1 must become 2, so I would like to insert a list of posts to change the permalink like that:

```
   $old_url = array(
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-1/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-1/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-5/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-37/',

    );
```

then he has to give me this as a result:

```
   $new_url = array(
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-2/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-2/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-6/',
        'http://localhost:8888/site/permalink-38/',

    );
```

once the permalink has changed it should automatically update the post permalinks.
i'm not that good at php code, could you help me? thanks :)

Comment: I see you've used `$posts = $query->get_posts();` and `foreach ($posts as $post) {` which is highly unusual, is there a reason you did not use a standard loop? None of the loop lifecycle hooks get fired this way, the entire posts array is referenced causing all the lazyloading to fire immediately, the current post is never set, etc

Comment: I also re-read what you were trying to do several times and could not figure out your specific goal, I have several competing ideas and interpretations that all clash with eachother, and don't know which one is what you wanted. Can you edit the question to explain better? Examples of before/after would also be helpful

Comment: hello i updated the content, i hope it is clearer now, thanks :)